# How can i prevent ScrollTo in specific status react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a Top Tab navigator "Segment", And scrollView contains Two-component,

When I swipe to left Or When press to tap navigator Title I ScrollTo next view, based on the current index I got from Map().

Now when I'm in the "Closed Tab" and click to closed again it navigates me to the next View.

[Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EZAb.jpg)

How can I prevent this?
If I'm still in "closed" and click on it again just don't navigate me to the next view and still on it?

Code

```
const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');
const Tabs = [
  {
    name: 'opened',
  },
  {
    name: 'closed',
  },
];
const AppointmentScreen = () => {
  const scrollRef = useRef(null);
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
        <View style={styles.boxHeaderContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.headerText}>
            Hello
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.boxHeaderContainer}>
          <HeaderAppointments />
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.appointmentsContainer}>
        {Tabs.map(({name}, tabIndex) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={tabIndex}
            onPress={() => {
              // Works for Android well!
              if (tabIndex === currentIndex) {
                return;
              }
              if (scrollRef.current) {
                scrollRef.current.scrollTo({
                  x: tabIndex === 0 ? width : width * (tabIndex - 1),
                  y: 0,
                  animated: true,
                });
                setCurrentIndex(currentIndex === 1 ? 0 : 1);
              }
              //   if (tabIndex === 0) {
              //     setCurrentIndex(tabIndex === 0 ? 1 : 0);
              //     scrollRef.current.scrollTo({
              //       x: width,
              //       animated: true,
              //     });
              //   }
              //   if (tabIndex === 1) {
              //     setCurrentIndex(tabIndex === 0 ? 1 : 0);
              //     scrollRef.current.scrollTo({
              //       x: width * (tabIndex - 1),
              //       animated: true,
              //     });
              //   }
            }}
            delayPressIn={0}
            style={[
              styles.appointmentsBox,
              {
                backgroundColor: tabIndex === currentIndex ? '#000' : '#fff',
              },
            ]}>
            <Text
              style={[
                styles.appointmentText,
                {
                  color: tabIndex === currentIndex ? '#fff' : '#000',
                },
              ]}>
              {name}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          height,
        }}>
        <Animated.ScrollView
          ref={scrollRef}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          bounces={false}
          decelerationRate="fast"
          snapToInterval={width}
          scrollEventThrottle={1}
          onMomentumScrollEnd={() => {
            if (scrollRef.current) {
              setCurrentIndex(currentIndex === 0 ? 1 : 0);
            }
          }}
          horizontal>
          <OpenedAppointments />
          <ClosedAppointments />
        </Animated.ScrollView>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default AppointmentScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a condition in onPress of the segment to prevent that action:

```
if(tabIndex === segmentIndex){
    return;
}
```

Comment: `segmentIndex` in this case it's the `index` in the State?

Comment: in this case the condition is `currentIndex === index`. You can try that

Comment: Sadly not works for ios IDK why, Is there deference between ios&android when pressed on Tabs when calling scrollTo, Here's A [Git](https://imgur.com/sgGHZZy) I record check it please to understand what I mean, and re-check the code in the question!

Comment: When I change on ScrollTo 

`x: tabIndex === 0 ? width * (tabIndex - 1) : width`

instead of

 `x: tabIndex === 0 ? width : width * (tabIndex - 1)`

it's work well on ios simulator! But not work in Android

Here's a [Live demo](https://snack.expo.io/@anastely/69b765) after changes 
Works well for both platform, Before changes nothing work (Android/ios)

Is RTL related?
Because my app is fully RTL "forced" :D